# Encapsulationn in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, encapsulation

Here is the nature of my problem:

```
function theObject(){
    this.theMethod = function(theParameter){
    //code that uses theParameter
    }

    this.anotherMethod = function(){
        for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
            document.writeln("<img src = 'loc.jpg' onclick ='" + this + ".theMethod(" + x  + ")'>");
        }
    }
```

I think it's pretty straightforward to see what I'm trying to do here...but it doesn't work.  The HTML doesn't know what any of my "classes" are.  I've tried many variations, including using getElementById().addEventListener() but with that route the for loop variable changes out from under me.

How do you do this?  NO jquery please AND "theMethod" must remain encapsulated.

Thanks

Comment: Look at the generated HTML: you're turning `this` into a string. Don't.

Comment: Avoid `writeln`, try `innerHTML` or `appendChild` then add the event in JavaScript not in a string.

Comment: You cant use 'this' in more than one level of nesting functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work well for you. [Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PEYDK/)

```
function theObject(){

  this.theMethod = function(theParameter){
    //code that uses theParameter
  };

  this.anotherMethod = function(){
    for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = "loc.jpg";
      img.onclick = this.theMethod.bind(this, x);
      document.appendChild(img);
    }
  }
}
```

Using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) requires ECMAScript 5 or higher. If you need to support old dinosaur browsers, please look into [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

If you still can't support `.bind`, @6502's answer is your next best bet.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use strings to set up events that work on closures; the correct way is instead:

```
for (var x= 0; x < 10; x++) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "loc.jpg";
    img.onclick = (function(self,x){
                       return function(){
                           self.theMethod(x);
                       }
                   })(this,x);
    document.appendChild(img);
}
```

I understand that the code seems convoluted and introduces `self` but this unfortunately necessary in Javascript because `this` is not just a regular local variable and because there is no local scope but only function scope.

Without this double wrapping trick (used often in Javascript) all the images would call the method passing the same value instead of the image index.

When you set up an event handler using a string the code will be `eval`uated in the global scope so in general it's impossible to have that code to use local variables. Moreover objects (like the current object reference by `this` in the constructor) and closures cannot be converted to string and parsed from strings.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that turning `function theObject = new function(){` into `var theObject = new function(){` will fix your problem.